# Monomorphisms of torsion-free sheaves induce monomorphims of their determinant line bundles.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, coherent-sheaves

I've been trying to understand the following proof in Kobayashi's book. Let me state some relevent definitions.

Let $X$ be a complex manifold and $\mathscr{O}_X$ its structure sheaf. A coherent sheaf $\mathscr{E}$ is torsion-free if the map $\mathscr{E}\to\mathscr{E}^{**}$ is injective. It is a torsion sheaf if the above map is a zero map. A torsion-free sheaf $\mathscr{E}$ of rank $r$ has a determinant line bundle $\det\mathscr{E}=(\wedge^r\mathscr{E})^{**}$.

> Every monomorphism $\mathscr{F}\to\mathscr{F'}$ between torsion-free coherent sheaves of the same rank induces a sheaf monomorphism $\det\mathscr{F}\to\det\mathscr{F'}$.

The proof goes like this:

> Outside their singular sets (where coherent sheaves are not locally free), the map $\mathscr{F}\to\mathscr{F'}$ and the induced map $\det\mathscr{F}\to\det\mathscr{F'}$ are isomorphisms. Hence, the $\ker(\det\mathscr{F}\to\det{F'})$ is a torsion sheaf. Since it is a subsheaf of a torsion-free sheaf, it must be zero.

My questions are in the following:

1. Outside their singular sets, $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{F'}$ are locally free. Since they have the same rank, the map $\mathscr{F}\to\mathscr{F'}$ has a cokernel which has rank 0 and hence is a torsion sheaf. But why is it necessarily zero so that $\mathscr{F}\to\mathscr{F'}$ is an isomorphism?
2. If $\mathscr{F}\to\mathscr{F'}$ is an isomorphism outside the singular sets, then $\ker(\det\mathscr{F}\to\det{F'})=0$ outside the singular set. Then, how do I conclude that it must be a torsion sheaf? I don't know its stalks inside the singular set. To show it is a torsion sheaf, I need to make sure every stalk is a torsion module.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't see that this is true without other assumptions. Let $X=\Bbb C$ and $\mathscr{O}$ be the structure sheaf. Then $\mathscr{O}\stackrel{\cdot z}{\to}\mathscr{O}$ is a perfectly good morphism of free sheaves with cokernel the skyscraper sheaf supported at $0$ with sections $\Bbb C$.

Perhaps there should be a modification of the proof here - since the cokernel is torsion, it's supported on a closed submanifold of strictly smaller dimension, and we can throw that in with the singular set as a locus we can ignore - we will still get that the map on determinant bundles is an isomorphism on a dense open subset, which is really the thing that makes the proof work.

2. Any sheaf supported on a submanifold of strictly smaller dimension is torsion: consider the action given by multiplying by a nonzero function which vanishes on this submanifold.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. Your second bullet point is very useful. So, your definition of a torsion sheaf is that in every stalk every element is a torsion element, correct?

Comment: Yes. Did something I write suggest something else?

Comment: Then, maybe I am just tired today but I don't follow your second point. Let's say $\mathscr{F}$ is supported in a proper analytic subvariety $A$ of the base manifold $X$ and $s_x\in\mathscr{F}$ where $x\in A$. Then, take some holomorphic function $f$ that vanishes on $A$, then why is $(fs)_x=0$? It is true that $(fs)_y=0$ for every $y\notin A$. It is also true that $(fs)|_A=0$. But I must've missed something obvious.

Comment: One more thing in my last comment: $(fs)_|A=0$ does not make much sense, since this is a section in an abstract sheaf and is not a function.

Comment: But the problem is $U\cap A$ is not open. Therefore, even if I am tempted to say $(fs)|_{U\cap A}=f|_{U\cap A}s|_{U\cap A}=0$, I couldn't.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I assumed you were working with a line bundle there where you could just evaluate (and then it would be literally true). How about this: any coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module supported on $A$ is actually a $\mathcal{O}_A$-module: we can see that if $g,g'$ are two functions on some open subset $U$ of $X$ taking the same value on $A$, then under the natural reduction map $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\to\mathcal{O}_A(A\cap U)$, we have $g=g'$. This means that any sheaf supported on $A$ is really a $\mathcal{O}_A=\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}_A$ module, where $\mathcal{I}_A$ is...

Comment: ... the ideal sheaf of $A$. By going to stalks, we see that for any $x\in A$, the stalk of any sheaf supported on $A$ is really a $\mathcal{O}_{A,x}=\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathcal{I}_{A,x}$ module, so it's clear that any elements in $\mathcal{I}_{A,x}$ annihilate this stalk, and therefore since this is nonempty (remember, the image of $f$ is in $\mathcal{I}_{A,x}$), we have shown the stalk is a torsion $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ module.

Comment: Let me formally understand what you meant. So let's $i\colon A\subset X$ be the inclusion, where $\mathscr{O}_A=(\mathscr{O}_X/J_A)|_A$. Then you considered $i^*\mathscr{F}$ whose stalk at $x\in A$ is just $\mathscr{F}_x\otimes_{\mathscr{O}_x}\mathscr{O}_{A,x}=\mathscr{F}_x/J_{A,x}\mathscr{F}_x$. Therefore, it seems that you implicitly assumed that the natural map $\mathscr{F}\to i_*i^*\mathscr{F}$ is an isomorphism? However, by computing the stalk at $x\in A$, we are going back to the basic map $\mathscr{F}_x\to\mathscr{F}_x/J_{A,x}\mathscr{F}_x$. Whether it is an isomorphism just means...

Comment: whether $J_{A,x}\mathscr{F}_x=0$. So, I still don't get it.

Comment: This map is an isomorphism for any closed immersion such as $A\to X$ - this is a simple exercise in sheaf theory. It can be checked on the level of stalks without invoking whatever stalk computation you claim there, so you can use that to see that the stalk is actually $\mathcal{I}_{A,x}$-torsion.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for your claim? If $i\colon A\subset X$ is a closed immersion (Actually, we just need $A$ to be a closed set), then $\mathscr{F}\to i_*i^{-1}\mathscr{F}$ is an isomorphism for sure. However, from https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08KS, $\mathscr{F}\to i_*i^*\mathscr{F}$ is an isomorphism if and only if $J_A\mathscr{F}=0$.